# Efficient way to create array of string

Tags: c++, string, c++11, vector, stdarray

I need to create array of string which one will be the more efficient.

```
1.std::array<std::string, 3>arr  {"aa", "bb", "cc"};
2.std::vector<std::string> arr = {"aa","bb","cc"};
3.string arr[3]                = {"aa", "bb", "cc"};
```

Note : All the string(aa,bb,cc) in my case is fixed during initialised time.
      please suggested any other way if any.

Comment: Do you ever need to resize the array? Pass it as an argument?

Comment: No this is fixed during the complie time . but i need to search the string from the  fixed array i.e in our case aa,bb,cc and return to search to caller.

Comment: @newcpp if the size is known at compile time and never changed at runtime, use `std::array`. Otherwise, use `std::vector`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`std::array<std::string, 3> arr{"aa", "bb", "cc"};` and `string arr[3] = {"aa", "bb", "cc"};` should be equally performant. `std::array` bakes the array size into the type so it doesn't degrade to a pointer with unknown size when passed around (just make sure it's passed around by reference to avoid copies), and has more C++ utility methods, but otherwise has the same performance and behavior characteristics as C arrays, so it's probably the way to go.

If you can use C++14, a very small improvement could be made by making the strings [`std::string` literals](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator%22%22s), which allows them to be converted from C-style strings to `std::string` slightly more efficiently (the size is baked in at compile time, so it can use the known length constructor, rather than the one that must first scan for the `NUL` terminator).

```
using namespace std::string_literals;

std::array<std::string, 3> arr{"aa"s, "bb"s, "cc"s};  // s suffix makes them string literals
```

Comment: I am using c++11 so i can't use std::string_literals; any alternative for it on c++11
any good way other than {std::string(aa),..,..}

Comment: @newcpp: The literals are mostly equivalent to using the pointer+length constructor for `std::string`, so `"aa"s` could be written more verbosely as a `std::string("aa", 2)` (but it means hardcoding in the lengths of each string). `std::string("aa")` gains you nothing at all (it's just writing explicitly what happens implicitly when you assign a `char*` to a `std::string`).

Answer (score 2):

I will go for 3rd one. Simple and there is no compile time or run time overhead off `std::array` or `std::vector`

```
string arr[3]                = {"aa", "bb", "cc"};
```

Comment: `std::array` should have no overhead beyond plain C style arrays, at least at runtime. It might slightly slow compilation given the cost of realizing the template at compile time, but other than that, it should behave equivalently.